# Java Distributed caching

Tags: caching, ehcache, oracle-coherence, hazelcast, infinispan

I'm researching distributing caching solutions for java.
I have to develop application that would be clustered on 5-10 nodes.
each node will have its own portion of cache.

I'm researching for distributed cache providers with fault tolorace: coherence, ehcache, infinispan, hazelcast...

I should process task on the node that contains the data.
thus I should be able to detect by API that object is in local node.

now hazelcast does this.
ehcache is bound to terracota server array and have not found way to do what i want(L2->L1 copying does not count)?
still researching infinispan.
have not come to coherence yet.
open minded for any alternative.

could anyone point products that is suited for my needs?
researching these details takes to read almost full documentation per product, so it goes really slow

Comment: Terracotta clustered Ehcache can do this using Quartz Where: http://terracotta.org/documentation/quartz-scheduler/quartz-scheduler-where#available-constraints

Answer (score 1):

Infinispan not only has the ability to store data in a distributed fashion, but it also comes with a [distributed execution framework](https://docs.jboss.org/author/x/LgY5) that should help you.